# Linkage matrix value error: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, hierarchical-clustering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VSyZ.jpg)I'm using Python, numpy and scipy to do some hierarchical clustering on the output of a topic model I created for text analysis.

I applied my testcorpus to the ldamodel so it became a bag-of-words representation. Then I turned it into a matrix. Now I want to use scipy to make a linkage matrix of my matrix. But it gives the Value Error: setting an array element with a sequence.
I guess that this is because only equally shaped arrays can be clustered. And my matrix has a difference in lengths between the lists inside the list of lists.
I just don't now how to solve this.
Here is a little part of the code. I don't know if it is helpful. I just really hope someone can help me.

```
  import numpy as np
  X = np.array(corpus)
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
  from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
  Z = linkage(X, 'cosine')
```

Comment: When you ask questions like this you need to identify the problem line, and tell us something about the inputs, arrays or otherrwise, to that line.  Look at my recent answer to another question with the same error,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621340/what-is-the-solution-python-gives-me-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with.  A crucial question in your case is the problem in the first or the last line?

Comment: HI, thanks for your comment. I'm pretty new in programming (linguistic student who had an introduction to Python). This may sound as a stupid question, but is it  possible to help me with how I can identify the problem line?

Comment: @hpaulj , Oh and the error occurs at the last line:  Z = linkage(X, 'cosine') . I can print matrix X without a problem, but it is Z that gives the error.

Comment: I added an image of the code to  my post

Answer (score 1):

As you'd mentioned getting matrix `X` from lda model, it might be a sparse matrix of some sort. You can convert to dense matrix by `X.todense()` and apply the `linkage` method.If the matrix is too large to hold in the memory you can do 
`Z=linkage(X.todense(),distance='cosine')`.

In some cases, changing the `dtype` of matrix helps.

P.S : I too faced the same issue and converting my sparse feature matrix (scipy.sparse.csr matrix) to dense solved the issue.